# restore permission of /etc in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I gave 777 permission accidentally to /etc in Ubuntu 12.04. How to restore it to previous state?

I din't even run any of service due to that.

What I did is fire below command in root directory.

```
sudo chmod 777 -R *
```

Please help me..!

Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a big mistake. Unfortunately you can't restore permission of /etc unless you have backup of the system. So either restore from the backup or re-install the system.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and even worst - I couldn't login to the machine.
It took me a lot of affort but in the end this is what i did:

1.) [Boot the recovery console option.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)

2.)Select remount read-write (in ubuntu 13.10 it in the **Grub** option)

3.)Select root shell

```
chmod 755 /etc <--to get it back to default  
sync
init 6
```